# Flutter SmsAutoFill getAppSignature throwing error

Tags: flutter

im getting this error when i try to get the signiture
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAppSignature on channel sms_autofill))
 `void getSignture() async { String signature = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature; print(signature); }`
this is my code to get the signiture

i have tried to set the value with then and its still same